# Use while loops in python to create sum of powers

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

The outcome of this function should be `[14]` but I cannot figure out how to get this! The function is supposed to, while using nested while loops, take the integers from `list_one = [1,2,3]` and raise it to the power of the integers in `list_two = [2]`, then sum them. EX) `1**2 + 2**2 + 3**2`. the answer would then be appended to a new list. If the lists were `list_one = [1,2,3]` and `list_two = [1,2]` the new list would contain `[6,14]`. I have been going back and forth between methods but I am super confused now. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This isn't domyhomeworkforme.com.  Post your code and we can help explain why it isn't working.

Comment: Is mandatory to use a while loop?

Comment: Well I first though of going through with a whileloop and taking [i] of base_list, raising it to the power of [i] of exponent_list, then appending that to a new list, then summing that list, then adding that sum to the final list, then doing that over and over till I get the answer. Make sense? Haha seems like a lot of work for something that seems so easy.

Comment: this is what I have given up with:'sum_of_powers(base_list, expo_list):                                                                     new_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(base_list):
        fin = base_list ** expo_list[i]
        new_list.append(fin)
        i += 1
    return new_list '                                                                                      and this is what i put in the main():                                                            'base_list = [1,2,3]
    expo_list = [2, 3]
    print(sum_of_powers(base_list, expo_list))'

Comment: yes @RaydelMiranda it is necessary. It actually calls for a nested while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to using a god-forsaken *while* loop....

```
def sum_of_powers(bases, powers):
    return [sum([base**power for base in bases]) for power in powers]
```

DEMO

```
In [2]: list_one = [1,2,3]; list_two = [1,2]

In [3]: sum_of_powers(list_one, list_two)
Out[3]: [6, 14]
```

As requested: the unnecessary and god-forsaken `while` loop version

```
def sum_of_powers(bases, powers):
    accumulator = []
    bases, powers = iter(bases), iter(powers)
    j, i = 0, 0
    while j < len(powers):
        sub_accum = []
        while i < len(bases):
            sub_accum.append(bases[i]**powers[j])
            i += 1
        accumulator.append(sub_accum)
        j += 1
    return accumulator
```

This is HORRIBLE practice and your teacher should be shot for forcing you to go through this in *Python* of all things. There are many languages where these are useful constructs. Python is ***NOT*** one of them.

Comment: sadly it is madatory to use NESTED whileloops haha

Comment: Thank you so much :) I just have no reaason why this would EVER be necessary but eh, what can you do!? I understand now. You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

In pure Python I would recommend such functions:

```
def sumpowers(a_list, power):
    return sum(i**power for i in a_list)

def sum_of_powers(bases, powers):
    return [sumpowers(bases, power) for power in powers]
```

and usage:

```
>>> sum_of_powers([1,2,3], [1,2])
[6, 14]
```